# PHPUnit - assertion failed but I want to continue testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

```
->assertTrue(false);
->assertTrue(true);
```

First assertion was failed and execution was stopped. But I want to continue the further snippet of code.

Is there possible in PHPUnit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just store up the failures for the end, say with a

```
$passing = true;
if (! false) { $passing = false; }
if (! true) { $passing = false; }
$this->assertTrue($passing);
```

but I highly discourage this form of testing. I have written tests like this, and they exponentially get out of hand, and worse, you start to get weird failures for hard-to-find reasons.

Additionally, smarter people than me agree, tests should not have any [conditionals](http://xunitpatterns.com/Conditional%20Test%20Logic.html) (if/else, try/catch), because each conditional adds significant complexity to the test. If a conditional is needed, perhaps both the test and the SUT, or System Under Test, should be looked at very carefully, for ways to make it simpler.

A much better way would be to change it to be two tests, and if they share a significant portion of the setup, then move those two tests into a new test class, with the shared setup performed in the Setup() method.

Answer (score 17):

The other answerers are correct - you really should separate out your assertions into separate tests, if you want to be able to do this. However, assuming you have a legitimate reason for wanting to do this... there is a way.

Phpunit assertion failures are actually exceptions, which means you can catch and throw them yourself. For example, try this test:

```
public function testDemo()
{
    $failures = [];
    try {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    } catch(PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
        $failures[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    } catch(PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
        $failures[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    if(!empty($failures))
    {
        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException (
            count($failures)." assertions failed:\n\t".implode("\n\t", $failures)
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, it tries two assertions, both of which fail, but it waits until the end to throw all of the failure output messages as a single exception.

Comment: nowdays the exception class is `PHPUnit\Framework\ExpectationFailedException`, but the rest holds :)

Answer (score 6):

that defeats the point of a unit test. you might want to break it into a few more test methods instead of having a monolithic test method.

Here is some pseudo-code, as a bad example.

```
MyBadTestMethod()
{
   someResult = MyMethod();
   assertIsCorrect(someResult);
   myResult2 = MyMethod2(someResult);
   assertIsCorrect(myResult2);
}
```

`MyMethod2` and `myResult2` will fail.

Here is a better example.

```
MyTestMethod1()
{
   someResult = MyMethod();
   assertIsCorrect(someResult);
}
MyTestMethod2()
{
   myResult2 = MyMethod2(someCorrectResult);
   assertIsCorrect(myResult2);
}
```

Comment: Like the OP, I needed the obvious answer.  PHPUnit continues after a failed test by default, just not within a single test.

Comment: @SethBattin so this is what you needed?

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party, but I recommend using a configuration file for the test suites to achieve this easily.

You can create `phpunit.xml` file from where you are running the phpunit test. Hence phpunit will run the needed tests listed there.

> PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from /path/phpunit.xml

In that file you can specify that you don't want to stop on failure.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" stopOnFailure="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Test">
      <file>tests/ClassTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only seems to apply to the whole testsuite. From the docs: _This attribute configures whether the test suite execution should be stopped after the first test finished with status “failure”_ https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html