# Is there a command to continue tests on failure in PHPUnit?

Tags: testing, phpunit

Is there a way to continue the the execution of PHPUnit tests when an assertion fails in the command line?

Is there for an example a flag for the PHPUnit Command like:

```
phpunit --continueonfailure
```

or something during an execution of a series of tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit - assertion failed but I want to continue testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832263/phpunit-assertion-failed-but-i-want-to-continue-testing)

Comment: Not quite - this is within a single test function. I would like to know if there was a phpunit --continueonfailure flag or something during an execution of a series of tests

Comment: @Jenski: You asked about this quite some time ago. During that time or later, Phpunit introduced caching results and then continuing at the last error(s) is made possible by putting previously failed tests to the top of the test-runner queue AFAIK. This should be the default behavior now (if result caching is enabled). Apart from that your IDE might support this directly, e.g. IIRC Phpstorm has a feature to re-run failed tests (for which you need to execute the tests within the IDE).

Answer (score 0):

I think PHPUnit by default continues to run tests upon failure. So you have probably defined `stopOnFailure="true"` in your `phpunit.xml`. Either remove that entirely or try setting it to `true`.

There are a couple of flags that you can append to your command that makes PHPUnit stop on error / failure:

```
--stop-on-defect            Stop execution upon first not-passed test
--stop-on-error             Stop execution upon first error
--stop-on-failure           Stop execution upon first error or failure
--stop-on-warning           Stop execution upon first warning
--stop-on-risky             Stop execution upon first risky test
--stop-on-skipped           Stop execution upon first skipped test
--stop-on-incomplete        Stop execution upon first incomplete test
```

You can [read more about phpunit.xml here.](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html)